# Block the camera object for my widget (getParameters failed (empty parameters))

Tags: android, widget, flashlight

I'm trying to make a widget for turn off and turn on the flashlight from the main screen. My problem is that I don't find the way to block the camera for the widget. If I open the native camera while the widget flashlight is turn on, my widget lose the camera instance and I can't recovery it if I open the widget again.

I obtain the next error when I try to recover the camera instance from the widget:

E/Camera: Error 2
getParameters failed (empty parameters)

I`m trying with the functions lock() (when the flashlight is turn on) and unlock() (when the flashlight is turn off) but don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you release the Camera instance, when another application uses it:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

Then when you move back to your widget you open Camera in onResume() again.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html